# Does using a Refresh Token require the original credentials?

Tags: oauth, refresh-token

I'm writing PowerShell scripts against the Bitbucket API to help manage users/groups/repo access etc. Auth is kicking my behind, however.

I've successfully got an access token and refresh token using the following:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $clientKey,$clientSecret)))
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
}
$body = @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials";
}
$content = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -body $body -Headers $headers
$tokens = [PSCustomObject]@{
    AccessToken = $content.access_token;
    RefreshToken = $content.refresh_token;
}
```

Note the use of `client key` and `client secret` above.

I figured that when I made a request that failed because the token expired, I would be able to use the refresh token to obtain a new one. However every example I can find uses the client key and secret *as well*. If I have the client key and secret (in a secure store), then I may as well just obtain a new access token directly, and ditch the whole concept of refresh tokens entirely.

Was the original idea of refresh tokens that they would work on their own (it is a "bearer" token, after all), or did the industry decide they're too powerful to be used that way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to provide the client key/secret again to protect against a hacker using a stolen refresh token to get new tokens.

The advantage of the refresh token is that the user does not need to be involved when the client wants to get new tokens. It would be more inefficient to have the re-authenticate and give consent each time. Refresh tokens also allow the application to get new tokens even when the user is not present.